# How to convert UTC time to local time in android for sunset time

Tags: java, android, timezone, utc

I am trying to get the sunset time for the users in there local time. I get the sunset time in UTC from sunrise-sunset.org. Then I convert it to local time, then I account for daylight savings time and then I convert it to regular time.

The problem is it comes out hours off.

**Edited**
For example:

In the app the user can set there location to anywhere in the world, let's say they set it to Springfield MO(USA). It returns  `04:57:31 AM`, after I convert it and what not it comes out to `5:57 AM`, even though it should say `4:57 PM`. That is for API 30.

Now what makes that even more strange is if I use a API 22 phone it comes out as `7:57 PM`.

I needed to support API 21 to API 30(Android 11).

Also it keeps returning daylight savings time as on, when it's not.

```java
   public void RequestSunsetTime(String lat, String lng){

        // set loading text
        sunsetTimeTextView.setText(R.string.loading_text);

        ProjectRepository projectRepository = new ProjectRepository();
        String url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng + "&date=today";
        projectRepository.requestDataPartTwo(url, new ProjectRepository.VolleyResponseListenerForTwo() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String UTCtime) {

                // convert utc time to local time
                String time = UTCtime;
                System.out.println("== TIME ==" + time);


                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                    Date  _date = df.parse(UTCtime);
                    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> Time zone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());
                    time = df.format(_date);
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> time: " + time);

                    // convert army time to standard time
                    String[] timeParts = time.split(":"); // convert to array

                    // fetch
                    int hours = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]);
                    System.out.println(">>>>> army time hours: " +hours);
                    int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]);
                 

                    // --- *.getDSTSavings()* adds time for day light saving time
                    int timeForDST = (((TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings() / 1000) / 60) / 60);
                 
                    System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>> time: " + time);

                    // calculate
                    String  timeValue = "";

                    if (hours > 0 && hours <= 12) {
                        timeValue= "" + hours;
                    } else if (hours > 12) {
                        timeValue= "" + (hours - 12);
                    } else if (hours == 0) {
                        timeValue= "12";
                    }

                    if(timeForDST != 0){
                        int num = Integer.parseInt(timeValue);
                        timeValue =String.valueOf(num + timeForDST);
                    }

                    timeValue += (minutes < 10) ? ":0" + minutes : ":" + minutes;  // get minutes
                 
                    timeValue += (hours >= 12) ? " PM" : " AM";  // get AM/PM

                    time = timeValue;

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>> Final Time: " + time);
                // save
       
              
            }

          

        });

    }
```

Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Please specify an *example* of the UTC time you get, the time zone you want, the expected result in that time zone and the full listing of output from your print statements. *The problem is it comes out hours off.* is vague for a problem statement and doesn’t give of enough to work with at all for helping you solve the problem. (Lemme guess, it may come out 12 hours off? No, wrong? You tell us!)

Comment: Consider not using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, built-in from API level 26 and for lower levels available through desugaring. See the answer by Basil Bourque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working much too hard.

Never use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone`, `Date`, and `Calendar` classes. Use only the *java.time* classes.

I’m not clear on what format of text you receive. I’ll assume it is standard ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ. (If not, edit your Question for clarity.)

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2022-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z" ) ;
```

If desired, lop off unneeded detail.

```
instant = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MINUTES ) ;
```

Adjust from an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC to a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) ;  // Or ‘ZoneId.systemDefault()`. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the time of day.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

Generate text in automatically localized format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
String output = lt.format( f ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/7KI78C).

These classes are built into Android 26+. For earlier Android, use the latest tooling with its “API desugaring” to access most of the *java.time* functionality.

Comment: The user can set the time for anywhere in the world, so is there any way to do the *Generate text in automatically localized format*  without setting the `Locale`?

Comment: @sundrycode A `Locale` is required for localization, providing the human language to use in translation as well as providing the cultural norms for capitalization, abbreviation, punctuation, and so on. To use the JVM’s current default locale, call `Locale.getDefault()`.

Comment: @sundrycode A `Locale` has nothing to do with the user’s location on earth. The locale is a user’s preference. A French-speaking professional from Québec attending a conference in Tokyo Japan will want to view the conference schedule in `Asia/Tokyo` time zone with `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH` locale.